# Quick smoke not working

Tags: smoke-simulation

I was just trying to add some smoke to a scene I made (I'm fairly new to blender and 3D), following a tutorial (then another one saying the same thing), but it doesn't seem to work the way it should. I did everything right, exactly like the guy in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtKQwN9P0sE.

The thing is that I tried doing it in a new project too and it worked. So something in the scene is causing this, I supposed...

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Just tried to do the simulation in another project then append it. It worked. Still, I want to know why I can't just make a new one there

Comment: Since it works in the new scene it's hard to say what causes these problems without knowing what the settings are... if it's important to know the exact reason you might consider uploading the *.blend file and add it to your question: https://blend-exchange.com/